# <<JavaGraphics` for ListPlot still not working in 12.2

Tags: plotting, bugs

### Bug introduced in 11.2 and persists through 12.2.

[A previous answer by Lukas Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207783/1871) gave some hope, where he outlined a method to change how the `$DisplayFunction` worked. I tried this method with no success. When I looked into `` Names[System`*Dump*] `` there is no `ListPlotsDump` or `ProtoPlotDump` anymore, so I assume whatever I change there makes no difference.

With

```
<<JavaGraphics`

Plot[Sin[x],{x,-Pi,Pi}]
```

I get a nice graphics window.

With

```
<<JavaGraphics`

ListPlot[{1,2,3,4,5}]

Out[] -Graphics-
```

there's no popup window.

Comment: you are in the right place to get help, just provide more details with the code you are trying to run so people can fix it or improve

Comment: "When I looked into `Names[System\`*Dump*]` there is no `ListPlotsDump` or `ProtoPlotDump` anymore" `ListPlotsDump` is still there, but `Names[System\`*Dump*]` won't find it, and you need to first execute `ListPlot` once: `ListPlot; ?"*\`ListPlotsDump\`iListPlot"`

Comment: I have updated my answer in the linked post, now it should also work with versions 12.1 and later

Comment: Yes it does. Now I have two working versions.

Comment: The updated version does answer the question

Answer (score 3):

The `show` definition from [Zachary Levine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26452/zachary-levine)

```
<<JavaGraphics`
show[x__] := Show[x, DisplayFunction->$DisplayFunction ]
show [ ListPlot[Table[i,{i,10}]]]
```

does the job.

Comment: This is very simple and works great, including from a text-based interface (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingATextBasedInterface.html). Cheers!